# Drawing SVG into Canvas and manipulating drawn elements using their IDs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I have an SVG file loaded into an `<object>` tag. I am using javascript to manipulate some elements within this svg. For example:

```
var theSvgXml = document.getElementById('theObject').contentDocument;
theSvgXml.getElementById('theElementId').style.display = 'inline';
theSvgXml.getElementById('theElementId').style.fill = 'red';
theSvgXml.getElementById('anotherElement').style.display = 'none';
```

This works perfectly and all was well. But i am wondering if the same thing can be done with canvas. I have read about kinetic js, fabric js, canvg js as well, and i saw the various methods of loading the svg file into the canvas either by the file directory, the xml or through an image.

But after drawing this svg file into the canvas, can i manipulate the elements by their IDs?

The SVG is created using Adove Illustrator, and each layer or group is given an id with can be accessed using css selectors. Again, can this be done in canvas after drawing the SVG onto it. (Please note that the SVG is HUGE and the only reason i am thinking about the canvas solution is because of the svg not showing the illustrator multiply effect to create a shadow)

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Code Snippet:

```
<g id="Pockets">
<g id="Pen__x26__Radio_Arm_Pocket" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Pen_Pocket_Arm" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Card_Zipper_Arm_Pocket" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Radio_Pocket_Arm_Pocket" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Angled_Chest_Pocket_Right" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Angled_Chest_Pocket_Left" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Angled_Chest_Pocket_left_and_Right" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Chest_Pocket_Right" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Chest_Pocket_Left" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Chest_Pocket_left_and_Right" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Tool_Pocket" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Cargo_x2F_Mobile_Pocket_Velcro" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Cargo_x2F_Mobile_Pocket_Zip" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Cargo_x2F_Mobile_Pocket_Button" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Cargo_Pocket_Velcro" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Cargo_Pocket_Button" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Cargo_Pocket_Zip" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Back_Pocket_Right_Velcro" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Back_Pocket_left_Velcro" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Back_Pocket_left_and_Right_Velcro" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Back_Pocket_Right_Velcro_Button" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Back_Pocket_left_Velcro_Button" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Back_Pocket_left_and_Right_Button" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Back_Pocket_Right_Zip" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Back_Pocket_left_Zip" class="st791"> … </g>
<g id="Back_Pocket_left_and_Right_Zip" class="st791"> … </g>
</g>
```

As you can see form the xml snippet after exporting the file from adobe illustrator, each group is set with an ID. How can preserve these in canvas as objects (as Fabrics.js suggests using getObjects() method)? Is there a way to achieve this? If yes, how can i reference these groups? Also, the shadow is a key issue and i do not want ot use flash. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by huge? Did you try to optimize the svg?

Comment: I mean there is over 20,000 lines of xml. It is a complex drawing with a lot of details.

Comment: Yes, with Fabric.js, you can manipulate SVG children separately.

Comment: @kangax Thanks for your comment. Please can you be more elaborate? I am importing the svg file with xml as you can see above. Can you give me an example on how to import the above svg whilst preserving the IDs as well as an example on how to manipulate them. Thanks

Comment: Sure, added an example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how to do this with Fabric:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('/assets/72.svg', function(objects, options){

  var group = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);

  group
    .set({ left: 300, top: 200 })
    .scaleToWidth(500)
    .setCoords();

  canvas.add(group);
}, reviver);

function reviver(element, object) {
  object.id = element.getAttribute('id');
}
```

The code should be pretty self-explanatory. We load SVG; Fabric parses it internally, spitting out set of objects representing each element. We then group those elements and add them onto canvas in one chunk. Reviver is responsible for reading id off of each SVG element and assigning it to a corresponding fabric instance.

Run this snippet in http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/ and you get:

[image: loaded svg]

Let's inspect this grouped object:

```
canvas.item(0) + ''; "#<fabric.PathGroup (29303): { top: 200, left: 300 }>"
```

And its children:

```
canvas.item(0).getObjects(); // Array[2287]
```

Let's retrieve one by id:

```
var greenland = canvas.item(0).getObjects().filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.id === 'path4206';
})[0];
```

This is all plain old Javascript, as you can see. Let's change color of that particular object/shape now:

```
greenland.fill = 'red';
```

[image: greenland in red]

Comment: Thanks @markE! I noticed you've been answering some Fabric questions on SO, but more Kinetic ones :) Do you prefer Kinetic over Fabric or is it that you're more familiar with Kinetic? Just curious. Would love to hear your thoughts on how 2 libraries compare and what makes you chose one over another.

Comment: WOW. @kangax Crystal clear answer. Thank you so much. I will try to get this method to work for me. Great library man. Great work.

Comment: This link http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink seems to work for kitchensink.

Answer (score 1):

`<canvas>` operates on pixels, it doesn't have the concept of objects/elements like SVG. So to maniupulate the image you'd need to manipulate the underlying SVG and re-render it to canvas after every change.

You can put SVG image on `<canvas>` using `.drawImage` method.

```
var cvs = document.createElement('canvas'), ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
cvs.width = 600;
cvs.height = 300;
document.body.appendChild(cvs);

var img = new Image();
img.width = '600';
img.height = '300';

img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
img.src = 'file.svg';
```

But you can't manipulate SVG created this way. To do this you should try to convert an `<svg>` element DOM do base46 encoded string, set it an a source of an image, then render to the canvas.

So in the example above instead of `img.src = 'file.svg'` you'd need

```
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa( document.getElementById('mySvgElement').outerHTML );
```

Comment: I kind of thought about that, but i have a problem with this method. As stated above the SVG is HUGE and it takes almost 5 seconds to render it to a canvas, which obviously is very bad to do every time i change something. Great answer though. Are you sure there is no way to alter the elements as i do with an svg?

Comment: There are no "elements" on canvas. Besides if it's so huge, it would still be huge (have the same number of objects). You could try to use some library designed to manipulate elements on canvas. Well, these libraries don't really manipulate elements on canvas but keep track of them internally and re-render when needed. It's similar to manipulating and re-rendering svg, but with an additional layer which may or may not use more resources.

Answer (score 1):

**Just some random thoughts about your situation**

While html canvas does have a few compositing modes, *canvas doesn't have an image multiply blend.*

However, Firefox does! It's a multiply blend extension to compositing:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'multiply';
```

The major canvas libraries that have SVG-->Canvas translators are FabricJS and KineticJS, but neither of them have implemented this multiply filter yet.  Of the two, FabricJS is more SVG capable at this point and I see Kangax (FabricJS's creator) has commented on your post.  You might ask him really nicely if he would add a multiply filter ;)

Since you seem to have access to Adobe Illustrator, you might try out Mike Swanson's impressive SVG-->Canvas translator.  I don't know if it handles image filters, but it does an impressive job of taking standard Adobe Illustrator SVGs and creating Canvas drawings (very impressive app, if you ask me!):  http://blog.mikeswanson.com/post/29634279264/ai2canvas

Thinking inside SVG -- you should check out the SVGJS library:

SVGJS is an SVG library that lets you manipulate SVG elements by ID.

https://svgdotjs.github.io/

There is also an extension that imports from Illustrator:

https://svgdotjs.github.io/importing-exporting/

And finally SVGJS also has an extension that does a darken image filter (not multiply, but close)

https://svgdotjs.github.io/plugins/svg-filter-js/

If you get desperate...(unlikely you'll get this desperate!)

You could "roll your own" multiply filter by grabbing the canvas pixels with context.getImageData and then running this function on each of the r,g,b elements of the pixels you want to multiply.

```
function multiply(top, bottom){
    return(top*bottom/255;
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a framework like kinetic then you can access and manipulate layers and objects by their id's or names.

Comment: Can you please provide me with a link to an example if possible? Or provide an example itself. Thank you.